# Get someone game status on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make my discord bot get someone current game and do something with it

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(prev,cur):       


    games = ["overwatch", "rocket league", "minecraft", "stardew valley"]
    
    print(cur.activity.name.lower())
    if cur.activity and cur.activity.name.lower() in games:
            #do somethig
```

this code works only if the user isnt using a custom status, otherwise it will show that instead of the game. and also for some reason it returns twice

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the user activity type you want to check by adding this to your if statement:

```
cur.activity.type == discord.ActivityType.playing
```

In your case the if statement will only trigger when the user is playing a game.

You can check other activity types [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=activity%20type#discord.ActivityType).